# How to resolve TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON when creating SP list item?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, ajax

Trying to create a list item in SharePoint using REST, getting the following error message:

Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Am I missing something obvious here?

```
$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists('" + myList + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'Title': 'testing',
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.List_x005f_TasksListItem' }
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            TX = data.d.Id;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User the following function to Create ListItem in SharePoint List

```
function CreateListItem(myList) {
var listMetadataType = "SP.Data." + myList + "ListItem"
var listNameInternal = GetListItemEntityTypeFullName(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, myList);
listNameInternal.done(function(data) {
    listMetadataType = data.d.ListItemEntityTypeFullName;
});

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + myList + "')/Items",
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
        '__metadata': { 'type': listMetadataType },
        'Title': 'testing',
    }),
    success: function(data) {
        TX = data.d.Id;
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});}

function GetListItemEntityTypeFullName(siteUrl, listTitle) {
    return $.ajax({
    url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle + "')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName",
    method: "GET",
    async: false,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    }
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add list item to list using REST API with jQuery code, the following code for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var listName="CustomList";    
function AddListItem(){
    var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
    var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
        "Title": "testing"
    };   
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Success');            
        },
        error: function (data) {
             alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
// Get List Item Type metadata
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}  
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="AddListItem()" value="AddListItem"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list name is "List_Tasks" then everything is fine in your code, you just need to add "/getbytitle" in your url after /lists.

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + myList + "')/items",
```